# How change display Command-T result

Tags: vim

When selecting a search result file, the file is opened in a horizontal separators. How to specify the settings that would be opened to Enter into an upright. (ctrl-v - still less convenient than enter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set all of the mappings in your vimrc. Check the command-t help for more information. For your specific question:

```
let g:CommandTAcceptSelectionMap='<C-v>'
let g:CommandTAcceptSelectionVSplitMap='<CR>'
```

That will cause enter to open the file in a vertical split and ctrl-v to open the file in the current buffer.

Comment: This won't work. Edit your question and add quotation marks to the options. Then I'll vote up your reply :P

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't actually try it since I like the default behavior.